# Using MS Sequel server with PHP on Mac returns returns a different query result then on a Windows machine

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, macos, sqlsrv

**Context**

We are using a Microsoft Sequel database and our application runs php (7.3 version) and everybody is using Windows to do their development. Recently I started using a Mac as a working station, installed apache and php (7.3) on it. To be able to use the MS Sequel database I installed the recommended drivers following this Microsoft tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15.

**Problem**

All of this is working well, except some queries return a empty result where the same query on Windows returns the expected (not empty) result. We suspect that the PHP drivers for MS Sequel are not working the same between the 2 OS’s. We use PDO_SQLSRV (5.6.1 version) extension in PHP.

We pinpointed it to the fact that a declare statement with assignment is returned as the first result set, where on Windows the result set of the actual select query is returned.

The query we use is:

```
$sql1 = "
declare @test bigint = 1
select top 3 name from sys.databases
";
$illuminate_connection->select($sql1)
```

Does anybody have experience with this? And would there be a fix/workaround without having to rewrite the code?

Comment: If the *exact* same query is being run against the *same* instance using the *same* credentials, against the *same* data, then the *same* rows in the result set will always be returned. If the result set is different (and by different, I don't mean the order when a unique `ORDER BY` clause isn't provided), then that means *something* **is** different. That is a fundamental fact. We, however, don't have access to your environments so have no way of telling you what that *something* is.

Comment: @Larnu _"... the same rows in the resultset ..."_ Nope - no order by clause means the resultset has an undefined set of rows due to the use of TOP. That doesn't explain the empty resultset but it does demonstrate that OP's assumption has an obvious fault. Perhaps the use of NOCOUNT is needed to prevent the "rows affected" message.

Comment: That's my point @SMor . If there's no `ORDER BY` then the the data set could be different, as the order could be. Otherwise, other than the order, the results will be identical (which combined with `TOP` could easily result in a completely different result set).